# Can I easily add a thermostat to a whole-house fan?

Tags: wiring, thermostat

Is there a straightforward way to add a thermostat to an existing (basic no-frills) whole-house fan? I'd like to be able to set it to shut off when the outside temp rises to a certain point--so that the fan shuts off automatically in the early morning.

A simple timer would probably be fine. Could the fan easily be wired to an off-the-shelf HVAC thermostat? (...and program the thermostat to turn off the fan at X a.m. if the indoor temp is above 0 degrees, say...) There is an existing central HVAC thermostat that could be replaced or added to if needed.

Comment: Is your fan hard-wired or plugged into an outlet?

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard if you use a line voltage thermostat.

Comment: @isherwood, it's hard wired...

Comment: @Tester101, interesting, I didn't know you could get a programmable line-voltage thermostat...I've found them online now after a specific search.

Comment: Huh, this timer (designed for a receptacle box) might be a fairly simple solution--the timing is probably the more critical piece (vs temp), since I can assume the fan will need to shut off around dawn, plus or minus:
http://www.homedepot.com/p/Honeywell-7-Day-Programmable-Timer-Switch-for-Lights-and-Motors-RPLS730B1000-U/206311889

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a timer,  it's easy to buy a line-voltage timer switch that you can drop-in where the current fan's on/off switch resides.

If you want a thermostat, as the comments said you can find a line-voltage thermostat. THen you just need to run the hot feed from the on/off switch to the hermostat and then on to the fan.

Another option would be to use any low-voltage thermostat in combination with a 120VAC relay, but then you've got more parts, and need a low-V supply for the thermostat, so I wouldn't choose this option :-)